# Javascript assignment as expression in fat-arrow one-liner

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha

I have a promise where I'm taking the eventual result from the callback and storing it in a value that's scoped outside of the current block in a `before` hook, all in one line, like this.

```
describe('mongo stuff', () => {
  let project;

  before(() => {
    return mongo.findFirst('projects').then(data => project = data);
  });

  it('should have the correct company name', () => {
      expect(project.projectName).to.equal('Company1');
  });

});
```

*Note*: Mocha, the test runner I'm using, [understands promises](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises). That means, placing a `return` statement before a promise in a `before` hook, or in an `it` test, will halt the execution of the next task in the mocha test runner until the promise has been resolved. In other words, `data => project = data` will always completely execute before any tests that evaluate the contents of `project` are run.

I use `data` as a temp variable just so I can assign it to the higher-scoped `project` variable. This lets me use it in some later test like in the example above.

I was told in a code review that using an assignment as an expression isn't as clear as writing it out.

```
return mongo.findFirst('projects').then(data => {
    project = data;
});
```

Which do you think is better? Do you have any solid justification for avoiding the one-liner?

Comment: Both are wrong. Keep your functions stupidly simple and simply write more functions instead.

Comment: [Unlike other Stack Exchange sites, which encourage general reference questions and offer broadly applicable answers, Code Review aims to offer customized advice specific to your code. To make that work, we need to see real code.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/52915) Keep this in mind for your next question.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I think is "bad" when using the one-liner arrow is the implicit return. Whatever the expression evaluates to becomes the return value of the arrow function. In the case of promises, you should be careful when returning from within `then` callbacks since the return value becomes the resolved value of the promise.

Now in your case, the return value of `then` isn't going anywhere since the promise is not being used. So it shouldn't matter which form you should use. Therefore it should be fine.

A bigger problem is the entire snippet. You should make sure that `project` has a value by the time the code using it uses it or ensure that the code using it only runs after you fetch the value of `project`. If possible, since you have to wait for `project` anyways, you can make the call to get `project` synchronous instead.

Comment: I count 2 bad things there ;) The other thing you dont mention is that the use of `project` up top smells like a global in the worst way.

Comment: I'll update my question to include a mocha tag, as well as [supplemental docs explaining how they understand promises](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises).